# Boost asio io_service requests limiting

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have an `io_service` with a number of threads, used for async execution of heavy operations.

The requests are generally assigned with some named logical resources. Now I need to guarantee one resource does not starve others, i.e. when one resource schedules requests much faster than another, the other's requests are executed and do not wait in the queue too long.

An overall idea  to achieve this is to limit the maximum number of requests executed at any given moment from one resource. Something similar to a strand, but limiting not to at most one request at a time, but to an arbitrary number of requests.

But how to do it elegantly with an `io_service`? My one idea is to create a number of strands per each resource, and wrap each request with a strand, choosing them in round-robin manner. This could work, but is not too elegant. Are there any better options?

Answer (score 0):

> My one idea is to create a number of strands per each resource, and wrap each request with a strand, choosing them in round-robin manner. This could work,

It will not prevent resource starvation. If you make it a strand-per-named-resource then you might not limit concurrent work effecively unless the number of unique named resources is low enough to satisfy your required limit.

> but is not too elegant. Are there any better options?

I'd say you need a proper queue. `io_service` internally does use a work queue, but it's not intended for priority queuing or resource-based scheduling. Why are you using `io_service`? Are you trying to avoid the work of implementing the queue(s) yourself?